# Wordpress Title Error

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php $custom_store_title = isset(appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name')); ?>

<head>

<?php if (isset($custom_store_title))
        { 
        echo "<title>".$custom_store_title." Coupon Codes | ". $custom_store_title." Promo Codes</title>";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "<title>" .  wp_title(' ') ." | ".  bloginfo('name'). " </title>";
        }
    ?>

</head>
```

Condition is not working properly.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
$custom_store_title = isset(appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name')); ?>
```

Which means `$custom_store_title` is set to either true or false.

Then you have:

```
if (isset($custom_store_title)) // if (true), essentially.
{ 
  // ... 
} else { //this will never happen }
```

What you need is:

```
$custom_store_title = appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name'));
if (isset($custom_store_title)) { 
    //do stuff
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: I used it too but
appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name')
is set in whole site

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` returns a boolean, so the following line is setting `$custom_store_title` to either true or false:

```
<?php $custom_store_title = isset(appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name')); ?>
```

I think you might mean this instead:

```
 <?php $custom_store_title = appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name'); ?>
```

Then instead of the other `isset()` you probably want to use `!empty()` because `$custom_store_title` variable will always be set but may or may not be empty:

```
<?php if (!empty($custom_store_title))
    { 
    echo "<title>".$custom_store_title." Coupon Codes | ". $custom_store_title." Promo Codes</title>";
    }
else
    {
        echo "<title>" .  wp_title(' ') ." | ".  bloginfo('name'). " </title>";
    }
?>
```